# Leaflet.js change layers with sencha touch

Tags: javascript, touch, extjs, leaflet

I'm creating an application for mobile devices with Leaflet and Sencha Touch. It will be a map so tourists can see where the restaurants or stores are. Because there are so much spots in such a little town it would be nice when users can switch between the type of "spot". So they can choose to see all the restaurants or the stores or whatever.

Is it possible people can do this with a dialog box in sencha or something like that?

I've already created groups with layers, so the restaurants and stores, musuems etc are in different layergroups.

Sorry for my bad English I hope you'll understand... :)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet API offer addLayer() and removeLayer() methods that may be use to add or remove your layerGroups
from the map...

You may use a dialog box that show a list of your layerGroups with checkboxes that will trigger these addLayer() and removeLayer() methods for the corresponding layer in a similar way the Leaflet built-in layers control will do it...

Regards

Etienne